# Тепловые карты Yandex: не удаётся навесить событие на клик по точке (или просто открыть балун - без разницы)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Использую плагин heatmap для  отрисовки тепловой карты. Однако возник нюанс, не получается отследить событие по клику по точке.

```
                heatmap = new ymaps.Heatmap(obj, {
                // Радиус влияния.
                radius: 15,
                // Нужно ли уменьшать пиксельный размер точек при уменьшении зума. False - не нужно.
                dissipating: false,
                // Прозрачность тепловой карты.
                opacity: 0.8,
                // Прозрачность у медианной по весу точки.
                intensityOfMidpoint: 0.05,
                // JSON описание градиента.
                gradient: {
                       0.1: 'rgba(128, 255, 0, 0.7)',
                       0.2: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8)',
                       0.7: 'rgba(234, 72, 58, 0.9)',
                       0.9: 'rgba(162, 36, 25, 1)',
                       1.0: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                   }
            });
            heatmap.options.events.add('click', function (e) {   
                console.log(e);
                var objectId = e.get('objectId');    
            });                    
            heatmap.setMap(myMap);
```

Comment: Вы ничего не путаете? Метки и их балуны ничем не перекрываются и они не относятся к heatmap, это либо независимые геообъекты, либо их коллекции или выборки в менеджере объектов, кластеризаторе или как ещё вы их на карту добавляете. Если же вы называете точками элементы тепловой карты, то кто вам сказал, что их можно отслеживать и как-то взаимодействовать? Документация ничего такого не предлагает. https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-heatmap

Comment: Ну да, необходимо отлавливать клики именно по элементам тепловой карты.  Вышел из положения поверх "тепловой карты" накидав метки. Хотя жутко не нравится такая реализация

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, модуль тепловых карт генерирует лишь графическое представление в виде тайлов. Какой-либо интерактивности такая интеграция не предполагает. Потому вы пошли верным путём, добавляя объекты альтернативными вариантами.